# Using fonts in modular documents

Tags: fonts, subfiles

I have a document with a structure:

```
+-- main.tex
+-- style.sty
+-- fonts
|   +-- times.tff
+-- sections
|   +-- section1.tex
|   +-- section2.tex
```

Main file main.tex includes section files via *subfiles* package.

Now I want to use my "times.tff" font in the document. So I include this part to my style:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Path=fonts/]{times.ttf}
```

And everything is working well, but only if I compile document from the main. If I want to compile only section 1, then I get an error:  *fontspec error: "font-not-found"*. This is because font path for section 1 will be different from the main.

How can I set the path so that I could compile from the sections?

Answer (score 4):

save the font file into your systems font directory or in TeX's font directory: `TEXMF/fonts/truetype/` For the latter run `texhash` of update the file name data base for a MikTeX distribution. Then you do not need to specify a path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it is not possible to install a font in any folders other than given.

Comment: You have at least a home (user) directory where you can create a `texmf` directory and then create `fonts/truetype/times.ttf``

Answer (score 1):

On a Unix-like system (all I know) you could create symlinks "`fonts`" to the top level "`fonts/`" repertory which is referred to by the main document. This could work. Untested due to absence of MWE.